# Removing all or most header from Django response

Tags: django, http, http-headers, django-views

I am connecting to my Django application through a raw connection.  Bandwidth in this application is scarce. This is the response I get.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 20 Jun 2012 07:58:18 GMT
Content-Type: application/text
Connection: close
Content-Length: 11
X-Varnish: 311740110
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish

My Webpage.
```

Is there a way to remove all the headers, and just return "My Webpage."?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Is bandwidth really that scarce?

Comment: Yes.  Also, it is more for the client to have to process.

Comment: That's most likely false because the client now has to parse the web page without metadata which means it may have to do more guessing before getting it right.

Comment: but most of the data is not useful to the client.  Server, Date, X-Varnish, Age, Via are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, headers were added for a reason and you may find that clients are unable to properly display your website without the headers.

That having been said:

To do this, I would add a middleware class that removes all headers in its `process_response` method. You'll need to put the middleware as the first item in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` as that means it'll be processed as the last middleware class before the response is actually sent to the user. See Django's [middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My understanding of middleware is that it will apply to all views.  Is there a way to only apply it to only some views?

Comment: Yes, you could add an attribute or some other info to a response object that a view returns. Based on that attribute you could filter the headers or not (because you have access to the response object in the middleware).